# What's wrong with vfs_stat() call?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, stat

I'm trying to do a stat on files,

```
    struct kstat stat;
    int error = vfs_stat ("/bin/ls", &stat); // /bin/ls exists

    if (error)
    {
            printk (KERN_INFO "error code %d\n", error);
    }
    else
    {
            printk (KERN_INFO "mode of ls: %o\n", stat.mode);
            printk (KERN_INFO "owner of ls: %o\n", stat.uid);
    }

    return error;
```

But error was always set to `14` (Bad Address), what's wrong with the code?

I'm running 3.9 kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vfs_stat()` is [defined as](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/stat.c#L102):

```
int vfs_stat(const char __user *name, struct kstat *stat);
```

and `__user` is [defined as](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler.h#L7):

```
# define __user __attribute__((noderef, address_space(1)))
```

In other words, `vfs_stat()` only supports using filename that is pointer into user space, and should not be dereferenced inside kernel space. Note that `"/bin/ls"` does NOT point into user space, but into kernel space, and thus cannot be used here.

Actually, error message 14 (bad address) tells this issue right into your face :)

Comment: Oh I finally get the `Bad Address` error message, thanks! What should I use in kernel space then? The string is not coming from user space

Comment: I think a better question is why you need to call stat from the kernel anyway? Mixing userspace design and kernel space design is a bad idea.

Comment: @tangrs I need to retrieve the owner and the mode of some binaries in kernel side, then I thought about kstat structure

Comment: It's actually not a fixed path, but to make it eaiser to test ;-P Solved by disabling memory checks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
#include <linux/uaccess.h>

int error;
mm_segment_t old_fs = get_fs();

set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
error = vfs_stat ("/bin/ls", &stat);
set_fs(old_fs);

...
```

Comment: As GKH points out in his [article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print), you should **never** do this.

Comment: @mvp **should**, *not* **must** :)