# How to read entire file with vfs_read in kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, readfile, kernel-module, filesize, vfs

I have to read an entire file in a buffer inside a kernel module I'm writing. I started following as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184274/how-to-read-write-files-within-a-linux-kernel-module.)

but, I'm not clear how to retrieve the file size, to allocate the memory for the array buffer. I could not find a good documentation of the VFS functions. (I'm working on 3.2 kernel).

How can achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By using `vfs_stat()` or `vfs_fstat` as answered in [How do you get the size of a file in the linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966071/how-do-you-get-the-size-of-a-file-in-the-linux-kernel)

Comment: Thanks, I used vfs_stat(). Now I get the "size" from the struct kstat. Seems that it is of type loff_t (long long). 
So, for example, printing the value with %lld, I see for "/bin/ls" : -131941060952272. 
This is impossible. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check if your arguments are correct and there is no error set by `vfs_stat()`

Comment: An example already exists at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19195560/whats-wrong-with-vfs-stat-call and you should have all the details at http://www.linuxjournal.com/node/8110/print

Comment: `-131941060952272` looks like a pointer. You probably have to deref it to get the actual value.